# Getting variable name in Python?

Tags: python

I have this method that takes in an unknown number of args and I have some variables from another class that I want to match the arg variable name to. The variable names are the same across this current class and the OtherClass. I was thinking something like:

```
def my_method(self, *args):
    for arg in args:
        OtherClass.arg_variable_name = arg # where "arg" on the right is the value
```

How could I do this effectively in python?

Comment: You probably want to use a `dict`

Comment: `x=5;def n(p):print "varname is ?"; n(x) ;` is the var name of 5 x or p ? multiple names can point to the same object... what is the actual variable name of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use **kwds instead of args. *args are values, so the caller can send it not with the variable, but just value itself.

```
my_object.my_method(1, 2, 3, "string")
```

If you use **kwds, you'll know the key, value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
dict( (name,eval(name)) for name in['self','args']
```

To get a `dict` with the values for each argument, and then from there you could match the `dict` values with your respective arg variable name.